# Checking if element is present using 'By' from Selenium Webdriver and Python

Tags: python, webdriver

I am attempting to validate that text is present on a page. Validating an element by *ID* is simple enough, buy trying to do it with text isn't working right. And, I can not locate the correct attribute for *By* to validate text on a webpage.

Example that works for ID using *By* attribute

```
self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.ID, "FOO"))
```

Example I am trying to use (doesn't work) for text using *By* attribute

```
self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.TEXT, "BAR"))
```

I've tried these as well, with *error (below)

```
self.assertTrue(self.is_text_present("FOO"))
```

and

```
self.assertTrue(self.driver.is_text_present("FOO"))
```

*error: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'is_element_present'

I have the same issue when trying to validate `By.Image` as well.

Comment: That is imported `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: I see `Identifier` `ID` `name` `xpath` `dom` `sizzle_selector` `link_text` `css_selector` `tag_name` `defaults` and `key_attributes`

Comment: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations

Comment: Yes, there aren't any. This leads to the suggested question, "how to check for text"

Comment: Your question is "how to check if text exists in the page" or "if one element with specific text exists"?

Comment: "if text exists on the page"

Comment: You can find the body element, get its text, then check if contains the text. It's highly discouraged though, I'd recommend you change your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's discouraged to do so, it's better to change your testing logic than finding text in page.

Here's how you create you own `is_text_present` method though, if you really want to use it:

```
def is_text_present(self, text):
    try:
        body = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") # find body tag element
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        return False
    return text in body.text # check if the text is in body's text
```

For images, the logic is you pass the locator into it. (I don't think `is_element_present` exists in WebDriver API though, not sure how you got `By.ID` working, let's assume it's working.)

```
self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.ID, "the id of your image"))
# alternatively, there are others like CSS_SELECTOR, XPATH, etc.
# self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "the css selector of your image"))
```

Comment: You're way is dead on. My check failed.

Answer (score 5):

From what I have seen, is_element_present is generated by a Firefox extension (Selenium IDE) and looks like:

```
def is_element_present(self, how, what):
    try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException: return False
    return True
```

"By" is imported from selenium.webdriver.common:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

There are several "By" constants to address each API find_element_by_* so, for example:

```
 self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "My link"))
```

verifies that a link exists and, if it doesn't, avoids an exception raised by selenium, thus allowing a proper unittest behaviour.

Comment: This is the one :)

Answer (score 0):

I like wrapping the whole thing into a custom assertion

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def assertElementIsPresentByXPath(self, xpath, msg=None):
    try:
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        self.assertTrue(True, msg)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        self.assertTrue(False, msg)

def test_element_10_should_exists(self):
    self.browser.get('url/to/test')
    self.assertElementIsPresentByXPath('//a[@id=el_10]')
```